# Get unique element on basis of string from array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{:a => "63-aaa",:b =>1}, {:a => "90-bbb",:b => 89}, {:a => "63-aaa", :b => 1},{:a => "45-hhh", :b => 44}, {:a => "32-kkk", :b => 67}, {: => "90-bbb", :b => 89}]
```

`a` key has value `63-aaa`, `90-bbb`, `45-hhh` and `32-kkk`.
I want to get the unique elements of the array on the basis of ids of values of `a` like:

```
[{:a => "63-aaa",:b =>1}, {:a => "90-bbb",:b => 89}, {:a => "45-hhh", :b => 44}, {:a => "32-kkk", :b => 67}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a block to [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-uniq) in this case:

```
arr.uniq { |hash| hash[:a] }
```

Comment: Hey its awesome working like charm, thanks for your help @Vu Minh Tan

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to care which one of each set of duplicates is kept. `Array#uniq`, with a block, is purpose-built for that. It will keep the one with the smallest index.  If you want the one with the largest index, just apply `Array#reverse` before and after `uniq`.

If, however, you wanted to use other information in each hash to determine which one to keep, you could do that by using the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that takes a block:

```
arr = [{:a=>"63-aaa", :b=> 1}, {:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>89}, {:a=>"63-aaa", :b=>22},
       {:a=>"45-hhh", :b=>44}, {:a=>"32-kkk", :b=>67}, {:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>14}]

arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update({ g[:a]=>g }) { |k,oh,nh| <code to return oh or nh> }
end.values
```

Suppose, for example, you want to keep the hash `h` for which `h[:b]` is largest:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update({ g[:a]=>g }) { |k,oh,nh| nh[:b] > oh[:b] ? nh : oh }
end.values
  #=> [{:a=>"63-aaa", :b=>22}, {:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>89},
  #    {:a=>"45-hhh", :b=>44}, {:a=>"32-kkk", :b=>67}]
```

I have created an empty hash (block variable `h`), and then for each hash `g` in `arr`, update `h` with the hash `f = { g[:a]=>g }`. If both `h` and `f` have the key `g[:a]`, the block

```
{ |k,oh,nh| (nh[:b] > oh[:b]) ? nh : oh  }
```

is called upon to determine the value of the key `g[:a]` in `h` (that is, which of the two hashes to keep). The block variables are:

```
k  = g[:a]
oh = h[g[:a]]
nh = g
```

(Note that `k` is not used in the block, so we might write the block variables as `|_,oh,nh|`.)

`each_with_object` returns

```
h = {"63-aaa"=>{:a=>"63-aaa", :b=>22}, "90-bbb"=>{:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>89},
     "45-hhh"=>{:a=>"45-hhh", :b=>44}, "32-kkk"=>{:a=>"32-kkk", :b=>67}}
```

so we merely have to extract the values:

```
h.values
  #=> [{:a=>"63-aaa", :b=>22}, {:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>89},
  #    {:a=>"45-hhh", :b=>44}, {:a=>"32-kkk", :b=>67}]
```

Another way is to first execute:

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:a] }.values
  #=> [[{:a=>"63-aaa", :b=> 1}, {:a=>"63-aaa", :b=>22}],
  #    [{:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>89}, {:a=>"90-bbb", :b=>14}],
  #    [{:a=>"45-hhh", :b=>44}],
  #    [{:a=>"32-kkk", :b=>67}]]
```

and then use whatever criteria you like to select one hash from each of the four arrays.

Comment: I have tried also this.Yes you are also right. Thanks for giving more knowledge on this. Thanks @Cary Swoveland